# PHP Prepend two elements to associative array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have the following array, I'm trying to append the following `("","--")` code

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Antarctica
        )

)
```

Current JSON output

```
[{"Name":"Antarctica"}]
```

Desired output

```
{"":"--","Name":"Antarctica"}]
```

I have tried using the following:

```
$queue = array("Name", "Antarctica");
array_unshift($queue, "", "==");
```

But its not returning correct value.

Thank you

Comment: `$queue = array("Name", "Antarctica");` is not the same as what you show at the beginning of the question.

Comment: If Your goal is to create such JSON, You should know that JSON objects are *unordered* lists of key-value pairs, so the effort would be senseless. See json.org - "An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs.".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The translation of PHP Array to JSON generates a **dictionary** unless the array has only numeric keys, contiguous, starting from 0.

So in this case you can try with

```
$queue = array( 0 => array( "Name" => "Antarctica" ) );

$queue[0][""] = "--";

print json_encode($queue);
```

If you want to reverse the order of the elements (which is not really needed, since dictionaries are associative and **unordered** - any code relying on their being ordered in some specific way is potentially broken), you can use a sort function on `$queue[0]`, or you can build a different array:

```
$newqueue = array(array("" => "--"));
$newqueue[0] += $queue[0];
```

which is equivalent to

```
$newqueue = array(array_merge(array("" => "--"), $queue[0]));
```

This last approach can be useful if you need to merge large arrays. The first approach is probably best if you need to only fine tune an array. But I haven't ran any performance tests.

Answer (score 4):

You can prepend by adding the original array to an array containing the values you wish to prepend

```
$queue = array("Name" => "Antarctica");
$prepend = array("" => "--");
$queue = $prepend + $queue;
```

You should be aware though that for values with the same key, the prepended value will overwrite the original value.

Comment: This doesn't make any changes to the array's numerical index too. If it had any. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$queue = array(array("Name" => "Antarctica")); // Makes it multidimensional 
array_unshift($queue, array("" => "--"));
```

**Edit**

Oops, just noticed OP wanted a **Prepend**, not an **Append**. His syntax was right, but we was missing the `array("" => "--")` in his unshift.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
$queue = array("Name" => "Antarctica");
$result = array_merge(array("" => "=="), $queue);
```

Comment: No, this only generates a single dictionary, not an array of one dictionary. You can use `$result=array(array_merge...);` though.

Comment: You are totally right:) Not fully understand this problem.@Iserni

Answer (score 0):

```
var_dump(array_merge(array(""=>"--"), $arr));
```